# Odoo javascript ir.actions.client with target: fullscreen and refresh page, have something wrong

Tags: javascript, python, css, odoo-10

I have do_action with javascript:

> var vals = {
>
> 'type': 'ir.actions.client',
>
> 'name': 'TEST',
>
> 'tag': 'TEST',
>
> 'target': 'fullscreen',
>
> }
>
> self.do_action(vals);

first, everything doing well, but

after refresh page(f5), odoo show left menu.....

i`try with:

> document.getElementsByClassName('o_sub_menu')[0].style.visibility =
>   'hidden';

But, all "o_sub_menu"(left menu) hidden.

Maybe something wrong with css?

someone can help me?

Thanks